# Browsing chrome extension code in visual studio

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, google-chrome-extension

I am relatively new at using visual studio 2013 but I have loved the ease of use it provides for browsing through the code. I need to browse some one else's chrome extension code that is a fork of a git repo. I have chrome extension template installed which lets me create chrome extension in VS but I am not able to figure out how to use it for opening an existing chrome extension. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about visual studio but you can use this chrome extension to view Source Code of any plugin
[Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en)

may be you can use visual studio once you open Chrome Extension archive.

Comment: I was actually hoping to use the IDE to understand the function calls, hierarchy etc. Not sure if we can do it with VS for js but do you know any other way?